# Why does compose() need an explicit cast when andThen() does not?

Tags: java, java-8, function-composition

I'm studying functional composition and have an example:

```
Function<String, String> test = (s) -> s.concat("foo");
String str = test.andThen(String::toUpperCase).apply("bar");
```

This example compiles and works as expected. However, if I change the order of the composition by using `compose()`, an explicit cast is required:

```
String str = test.compose((Function <String, String>) 
                          String::toUpperCase).apply("bar");
```

Without explicitly casting `String::toUpperCase` to `Function <String, String>`, there is a compiler error:

```
Error:
incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) V
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.Locale)
String s = test.compose(String::toUpperCase).apply("bar");
           ^-------------------------------^
```

The question is why `compose()` requires explicit cast and `andThen()` does not in this case?

Comment: I don not know rules for original post editing precisely but the error compiler returns in my case is defferent than in the edited version of the post:

Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        The type String does not define toUpperCase(Object) that is applicable here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error message shows, the problem is to do with the fact that `toUpperCase` has an overload which accepts a `Locale` as an argument, so the compiler error is caused by not knowing which overload `String::toUpperCase` is supposed to refer to. In principle the compiler should be able to know that a method reference with two arguments (the `String` object itself is the first argument) can't be a `Function`, but I suppose there just isn't a rule for this - or rather, there doesn't seem to be a rule for this *during inference of generic type parameters*, which is why the explicit cast solves the problem.

We can confirm that the overload is indeed what's causing the problem by trying a different method reference like [`String::trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--), which does not have overloads:

```java
// works without an explicit cast
String str = test.compose(String::trim).apply("bar");
```

So the question now is why the overload doesn't cause a problem when composing with `andThen`. The difference is that `andThen` composes the two functions in the opposite order, so the type parameter which needs to be inferred is the *output* type of `String::toUpperCase`, which is `String` regardless of which overload is chosen. So it seems that the compiler has a rule to handle the ambiguity of overloads during type parameter inference when the return type of the method reference will be used for inference, and the overloads have the same return type. Note that a similar rule can't exist for overloads with the same parameter types, because overloads *cannot* have the same parameter types.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down as an attempt (a rough one) to explore why the compiler issues the error.

#### 1. The difference between `andThen` and `compose` in this context

Here are the signatures of the two methods (omitted `default`):

```
<V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after)
<V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before)
```

Remembering that `Function` is declared with two type variables, `<T, R>`, the most significant difference between `after` and `before` in this context is that `after` is expected to take in a parameter whose data type is `R`, the current function's return type, whereas the data type of `before`'s parameter is `compose`'s local type variable, `V`, which the compiler *must infer*.

Why is this relevant?

#### 2. Why does `test.andThen(String::toUpperCase)` work?

Among the many things that the compiler is trying to do, it's trying to validate that `String::toUpperCase` is a valid argument to `andThen` and `compose`. To do that, it needs to establish the type of `String::toUpperCase`, meaning it needs to infer the data type of the method reference in that invocation context. Well, the compiler knows that `String::toUpperCase` must be a `Function`, so it just needs to infer the type arguments for `Function`, which is where the difference above applies:

- In the case of `after` (the parameter of `andThen`), the first parameter of `Function<? super R, ? extends V>`, is known to be (roughly) `R`, which has to be the same as the current function's (`test`'s) return type. And the second type parameter, `V`, which also corresponds to `andThen`'s local type variable, is inferred to whatever the method reference will be declared to return.
- In the case of `before` (the parameter of `compose`), the first parameter's type is unknown, and has to be inferred in context. It corresponds to `compose`'s type variable `V`. This is where the first difference is.

In Eclipse, the compiler error was `The type String does not define toUpperCase(Object) that is applicable here`, which gives the clue that the error is related to matching the argument type for `String#toUpperCase`.

Now, if you see above:

- `after` is a `Function` that takes a `String` parameter, which makes it somehow simple for the compiler to resolve the `String` method that `String::toUpperCase` is targeting. This is a massive topic on its own, but it boils down to the compiler choosing to link the function roughly as the lambda expression `(String s) -> s.toUpperCase()`. Method references can resolve to instance methods like that, where the first parameter of the function becomes the target of the method invocation (without parameters in the case of `Function<T, U>`).
- `before` could have been resolved in the same way, except that the compiler does NOT know for sure what the type of `Function`'s first type argument is. And because `String#toUpperCase` is overloaded, the compiler can't just decide to infer it as `(String s) -> s.toUpperCase()`, because `V` could have been meant to be of a data type that would force it to resolve the method reference to the overload, `String.toUpperCase(Locale)`. In other words, the compiler is dealing with a chicken-and-the-egg situation (where it needs to know the parameter type `V` to decide which `String#toUpperCase` method to link, but can't use `String#toUpperCase` signature to infer `V`, because there are two possibilities making it ambiguous).

#### 3. How you solved it

You got this code to compile by casting `String::toUpperCase` to `Function<String, String>`. What did that do? It simply got the compiler out of the above dilemma: you told the compiler that `V` is `String`, not `Locale` or any other possibility, which caused the compiler to resolve the method reference as `(String s) -> s.toUpperCase()` (leaving no room for `String.toUpperCase(Locale)` to be a valid option)

#### 4. Other ways to solve it

You can effectively do the same thing by forcing an explicit type argument for `before`'s `V`:

- `test.compose((String s) -> s.toUpperCase()).apply("bar");` will compile because `(String s)` explicitly types the data type of `before`'s parameter
- `test.<String>compose(String::toUpperCase).apply("bar");` does the same thing by helping the compiler's inference logic, telling it that `V` is a `String`, which avoids the chicken-and-the-egg situation referred to above.

This type of solution is not some strange approach, you're essentially doing the same thing that the cast in `System.out.println((String)null)` does when `System.out.println(null)` is rejected by the compiler, although these `Function` methods include generics as a spice.

Comment: From my tests, it seems, `javac` is actually doing the same as Eclipse, inferring `Object` because the ambiguous method reference can’t help here, then does not find a matching method, as `toUpperCase()` requires a `String`, followed by doing a wrong analysis for the error reporting. The error reporting code seems to fail to recognize that the method is not `static` and considers `toUpperCase()` inapplicable due to having no parameters and `toUpperCase(Locale)` to have to correct number of parameters, but “java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.Locale”.

Answer (score 1):

Because of its definition. The method [`Function#compose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-) is defined as this:

```
<V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before)
```

... where `V` is the extra type of input to the before function, and to the composed function. Therefore it additionally requires defining a generic parameter type, because the `Function<T, R>` knows only `T` and `R`. No explicit casting is needed:

```
String str = test.<String>compose(String::toUpperCase).apply("bar");
```

Interference doesn't work here because of the ambiguity of `String::toUpperCase`. More self-explanatory example is a function chain of `LocalDateTime` -> `LocalDate` -> `String`:

```
Function<LocalDate, String> test = LocalDate::toString;
String str = test.compose(LocalDateTime::toLocalDate).apply(LocalDateTime.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer:

It is because of the order in which these methods work. The `Funtion#andThen` method works opposite of the `Function#compose` method.

#### Details:

[`Funtion#andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) documentation:

> Returns a composed function that first applies this function to its
> input, and then applies the **after function** to the result.

[`Function#compose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-) documentation:

> Returns a composed function that first applies the before function to
> its input, and then applies **this function** to the result.

So in the case of `Funtion#andThen`, the type inference of arguments is already available to the compiler while in the second case (i.e. `Function#compose`) it is not.

By the way, I prefer to use `compose` this way:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<String, String> test = (s) -> s.concat("foo");
        Function<String, String> upper = String::toUpperCase;    
        String str = test.compose(upper).apply("bar");
        //...
    }
}
```